# Python dictionary : updating using .append

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm using python 3.7.4. I have the following nested dictionary:

```
dict = {'name': {'first': 'Alan', 'surname': 'Dunn'},
       'jobs': {'nurse', 'consultant'},
       'age': 76}

print(rec)
```

I want to use .append to add a new job description like this:

```
dict['jobs'].append('doctor')
```

But I get the error message:

`'set' object has no attribute 'append'`. Why is this? I've read some guidance that suggests using `.update` but I'm just wondering why I can't use`.append`. Python version maybe?

What is generally seen as the best way to do this?

Comment: Because set objects don't have that method in any version of Python. *Lists* do, sets have .add.

Comment: You're overcomplicating your question by including the dictionary. The question boils down to "Why does `{'nurse', 'consultant'}.append('something')` give me an `AttributeError`".

Comment: @JoeIddon because it's been asked over and over and over again, both generally (foo has no attribute bar) and specifically (set, append). The Python docs (or help, dir, ...) tell you what the attributes of a set are, so it's trivial to disabuse yourself of the assumption that append is one of them. This has no value to anyone but the OP, and only very marginally them (they'd arguably benefit much more from *researching and figuring it out*). It meets 2/3 criteria for downvotes and various of the close reasons.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If its been asked repeatedly, why not find a suitable duplicate?

Comment: @RoadRunner by all means, do

Comment: @JoeIddon i'm reading a book on python that suggests that creating the dictionary as I have in my question, and then using `append()` to add something to the dictionary. The book suggests to do it exactly how I have spelt it out in my question. Maybe it was poorly worded but I wanted to know if an earlier version of python would let you use .append() on a set, since the book I'm reading (2019) suggests that method. Maybe it's a typo/error in the book but I thought it could be to do with the version of python I was using. 

In any case I now know I can use `.add()`.

Comment: @Mrmoleje you should check the errata of the book, and report it to the publisher if not already present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary is a collection of key, value pairs. The values can be of any type. Here the value of the key `jobs` is of type `set`. If it were of type `list`, then, yes, you could use the `.append` method. But alas it is not so you can't. You can `.add` to a set, but this may not be what you are looking for if you want a data-structure that you can index (a set is a collection of hashable objects - there is no concept of order, whereas there is in a list).

These examples should get across the core ideas of lists and sets:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l.append(4)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l[3]
4
>>> s = {1, 2, 3}
>>> s.add(4)
>>> s.add('hello')
>>> s
{1, 2, 3, 4, 'hello'}
>>> s.add(-100)
>>> s
{1, 2, 3, 4, -100, 'hello'}
>>> -100 in s
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The append () function is not the property of a dictionary. It is for a list to add new elements to the list. So that you are recommended to use .add() function to add a new element in the dictionary as follow:

```
dict['jobs'].add('doctor')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer here lies in your error message...

> 'set' object has no attribute 'append'.

The value at key `jobs` is not a `list` its a `set`. That means instead of using the `append` method you need to use the `add` method

```py
dict = {'name': {'first': 'Alan', 'surname': 'Dunn'},
       'jobs': {'nurse', 'consultant'},
       'age': 76}

dict['jobs'].add('doctor')
```

```sh
>>> dict['jobs']
{'nurse', 'consultant', 'doctor'}
```